# Python Django Test for One of Two Exceptions

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-unittest

I am trying to test that a certain instance of a model will raise one of two exceptions, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. Here is what I have:

#### Model

```
class AvailablePermissions(models.Model):
    # Main Checkbox.
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
    # Checkboxes under Main Checkbox.
    subcategory = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
    # The view to grant permission to.
    view_name= models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    def full_clean_save(self):
        try:
            name = resolve(reverse(f'{self.view_name}'))
            self.full_clean()
            self.save()
        except NoReverseMatch as nrme:
            raise nrme
        except ValidationError as ve:
            raise ve
        return self
```

#### Test

```
# Default permission object "(**permission)"
permission = {
            'category': 'Category',
            'subcategory': 'Subcategory',
            'view_name': 'employee:create_profile',
            }
available_permission = AvailablePermissions(**permission)

class AvailablePermissionsValidationTest(TestCase):

    def test_AvailablePermissions_will_not_save_blank_permissions(self):
        for field in permission:
            original_value = permission[field]
            permission[field] = ''

            with self.assertRaises(ValidationError or NoReverseMatch):
                AvailablePermissions(
                    **permission
                ).full_clean_save()

            permission[field] = original_value
```

It throws the `NoReverseMatch` error, but I can't figure out how to look for "either or" exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
    try:
        AvailablePermissions(
            **permission
        ).full_clean_save()
    except NoReverseMatch:
        raise ValidationError
```

But do you really want to do that?  Generally with unit testing the desire is to exercise all of the possible paths.  This would just guarantee one of two paths were tested.

Comment: Maybe not? What would you recommend? As an aside, I had to add a message to the `ValidationError('NoReverseMatch Error')`

Comment: It is usually best too use two different tests for each error type and then figure out how excite the error independently.  So in this case inject a view_name that will cause the appropriate error for each test.

Comment: `def test_AvailablePermissions_only_saves_if_view_exists(self):` - To pass this test I broke the one above and couldn't figure out how to rewrite it with only a small amount of code.